# Acer Aspire One in infinite loop after it demands that I use eRecovery

Tags: boot, netbook, multi-boot, acer-aspire-one, infinite-loop

I have an Acer Aspire One that is dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04. After not using the netbook for about a month, I turn it on to use the Windows partition. Windows decided that I need to use eRecovery to 'recover' my netbook even though nothing was wrong with it. That doesn't work (it kept asking me to recover my netbook and never let me go back to windows). Because I have Ubuntu installed, GRUB found a Windows Vista partition on the netbook as well (Its always been listed there since I installed Ubuntu) so I decided that maybe I could just with Windows Vista. Turns out that booting into Vista fixed my problem (and it was running Windows 7). After it installed some updates it rebooted (WITHOUT MY PERMISSION) and now it just runs in an infinite loop booting and then rebooting every 2 seconds.

Any ideas?

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  FYI, Vista and 7 are essentially the same OS (most of the differences are graphical or otherwise not visible to other operating systems) so what GRUB (probably actually GRUB2) detected as Vista was really 7.

Comment: @CarlF, thanks for the input. In grub, it says that they are on separate partitions. Do you suppose that grub detected my Acer recovery partition as a Windows Vista partition?

Comment: Yes.  My Gateway netbook (apparently a rebranded Acer) has a recovery partition, and Debian's GRUB detects it as a Windows Vista installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was able to fix this (hopefully). I had to create an Ubuntu live CD for my netbook and then follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) to get it to work again. My guess was that when it forced me to 'recover' my operating system it screwed up the MBR. Fixing this fixed my problem... for now.